# Web Share API Fallback

Tags: web, share, fallback

I am implementing the new Web Share API for a site I am working on (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share). While it is supported by Safari Desktop, iOS Safari, and Android Chrome, it isn't supported by any other browsers. Is there a fallback that I can use for non-supported browsers to be able to share text and a link from my site?

Answer (score 0):

One fallback I use is Blob, see an example in here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-leaf-imu3w 
It uses 'saveAs' library from npm.

```
const blob = new Blob(['"Name","Value"\r\n"Alice","100"\r\n"Bob","200"'], {
  type: "text/csv"
});
saveAs(blob, "file.csv");
```

Another suggestion is to just show a regular page where the user can select data and copy it

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late now, but as you can see from under Usage section, the line

```
`.catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));`
```

provides a way to check for this. So then you can listen for the error, and write out custom sharing buttons if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check.web share API uses navigator.share

```
if (navigator.share) {
     navigator.share({ 
        title: 'harish tech',
        text: 'Check out harishtech.com.', 
         url: 'https://harishtech.com', 
     }) 
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
     .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
 }else{
    // Your fall back code here
}
```

For more info check out the link [share like native app](https://harishtech.com/articles/sharing-at-next-level.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, as a fallback in a React project, we built a second component triggering our own modal and used https://github.com/nygardk/react-share:

```
export const ShareButton = props => {
  if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && typeof navigator.share !== "undefined")
      return <ShareButtonNativeModal {...props} />
  else
    return <ButtonShareModal {...props} />
}
```